# google charts - histograms: remove horizontal division of items

Tags: charts, google-visualization

This is the almost-default configuration of histogram for Google Charts:

```
...
var options = {
                title: 'Some histogram',
                legend: { position: 'none' },
            };
....
```

and this is what it renders:

[image]

How can I remove the little horizontal dividers (pointed at on a screenshot) that divide blue "data bricks" that form the histogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `histogram.hideBucketItems: true` to the options...

```
var options = {
  title: 'Some histogram',
  legend: { position: 'none' },
  histogram: {
    hideBucketItems: true
  }
};
```

from the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram#configuration-options)...

> `histogram.hideBucketItems` - Omit the thin divisions between the blocks of the histogram, making it into a series of solid bars.